# Regex: Extract records from text file

Tags: python, regex

I am learning Regex and I want to extract all record from a file. The file has several records of the form `id-<'sequence of multiline special characters, digits and alphabets'>`.

I have written the following regex, it returns all but the last record. I know that the issue is that the last record has no tailing `id-` since it encounters eof.

What is the most efficient way to tackle this problem?

```
with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
    data = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    for result in re.findall('id-(.*?)id-', data, re.S):
        print result
```

EDIT: each record also has a parent-id field:

```
id-c0nv*&*parentid-t1_cwi2*&*auth-author*&*body-something something.
```

ANSWER: re.findall(r'(?si)\bid-(.*?)(?:\bid-|$)', data, overlapped=True)
I used the regex module since I wanted overlapping matches.

Comment: What's your file looks like? An example?

Comment: @KevinGuan Please check the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Another option may- it is positive lookaround.
Let's file content is

```
dsafdsfid-<'sequence of multiline special characters, digits and alphabets'>id-
sadddid-sdlkllkd   87   id-dfdssdfdsf

alksdlid-lklasdl
```

**regex is**

```
(?<=id-)(.*?)(?=id-|$)
```

**Explanation of regex**

```
capture all between id- and id- or string end
```

Try as below

```
import re
mtches = re.findall(r'(?<=id-)(.*?)(?=id-|$)',open(r"C:\Users\Winrock\Desktop\ids.txt",'rb').read())
print mtches
```

Prints

```
["<'sequence of multiline special characters, digits and alphabets'>", 'sdlkllkd 87   ', 'lklasdl']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the regex to look for the subpattern or the end of the string:

```
id-(.*?)(?:id-|$)
```

Comment: Works. Thanks so much. Can you explain the last parenthesis?

Comment: `(?:id-|$)` it will look for `id-` or `line end`

Comment: It's a group construct; saying match `id-` or the end of the string.

Comment: Cool. Turns out I am get erroneous result due to a parent-id field in the record. That is messing up with the id- and giving incomplete records.

Comment: @hwnd The file has records of the form: id-c0nv*&parentid-t1_cwi2&auth-author&*body-something something.

Comment: Use word boundaries: `for result in re.findall(r'(?si)\bid-(.*?)(?:\bid-|$)', data):`

Comment: This regex works but it gives non overlapping matches, hence, skipping alternate records. I used the regex module to allow overlapping matches. Thanks @hwnd